# How do I run graphx with Python / pyspark?

Tags: python, hadoop, graph-theory, apache-spark

I am attempting to run Spark graphx with Python using pyspark.  My installation appears correct, as I am able to run the pyspark tutorials and the (Java) GraphX tutorials just fine.  Presumably since GraphX is part of Spark, pyspark should be able to interface it, correct?

Here are the tutorials for pyspark:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/quick-start.html
http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html

Here are the ones for GraphX:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/graphx-programming-guide.html
http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/graph-analytics-with-graphx.html

Can anyone convert the GraphX tutorial to be in Python?

Comment: There are some interesting updates on the Apache Jira ticket http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3789

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like the python bindings to GraphX are delayed at least to Spark <strike>1.4</strike> <strike>1.5</strike> ∞. It is waiting behind the Java API.

You can track the status at [SPARK-3789 GRAPHX Python bindings for GraphX - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3789)

Comment: Hi, Misty do you have any idea when it will be released ? I have checked it's not available till now even on 1.5.1.

Comment: This is a terrible shame. It seems igraph-python is also partly dead. Is there any other option for handling large graphs in python?

Answer (score 23):

You should look at GraphFrames (https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes), which  wraps GraphX algorithms under the DataFrames API and it provides Python interface.

Here is a quick example from https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/quick-start.html, with slight modification so that it works

first start pyspark with the graphframes pkg loaded

`pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6`

python code:

```
from graphframes import *

# Create a Vertex DataFrame with unique ID column "id"
v = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
], ["id", "name", "age"])

# Create an Edge DataFrame with "src" and "dst" columns
e = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "b", "friend"),
  ("b", "c", "follow"),
  ("c", "b", "follow"),
], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])
# Create a GraphFrame
g = GraphFrame(v, e)

# Query: Get in-degree of each vertex.
g.inDegrees.show()

# Query: Count the number of "follow" connections in the graph.
g.edges.filter("relationship = 'follow'").count()

# Run PageRank algorithm, and show results.
results = g.pageRank(resetProbability=0.01, maxIter=20)
results.vertices.select("id", "pagerank").show()
```

Comment: You could put more explanation other than the links

Answer (score 3):

GraphX 0.9.0 doesn't have python API yet. It's expected in upcoming releases.

Comment: So basically GraphX is a Scala-only system since it does not have a Java API either?

Comment: AFAIK it's still Scala-only

Comment: Actually I think they do have one. See here: https://github.com/amplab/graphx/tree/master/python/examples

Comment: The original implementation by amplab included a couple of examples, transitive closure and PageRank, but without using the actual GraphX API, just regular PySpark API. GraphX includes a lot of handy functions and classes that are not exposed yet to Python.

Comment: I just found that it's done now: https://github.com/kdatta/spark/tree/SPARK-3789/python/pyspark/graphx Maybe it'll be included in the next release.

Comment: @JavierdelaRosa That looks like a fork.

Comment: @EvanZamir I think now [GraphFrames](http://graphframes.github.io/) is the way to go.