# Is Graph available on pyspark for Spark 3.0+

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx

I was wondering if GraphX API is available in PySpark for Spark 3.0+?
I'm not finding any of that sort in official documentation. All the examples are developed with Scala. And Where can I get more updates about it.

Thanks,
Darshan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run graphx with Python / pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302270/how-do-i-run-graphx-with-python-pyspark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation available at http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/graph-analytics-with-graphx.html:

**"The GraphX API is currently only available in Scala but we plan to provide Java and Python bindings in the future."**

However, you should look at GraphFrames (https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes), which wraps GraphX algorithms under the DataFrames API and it provides Python interface.

Here is a quick example from https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/quick-start.html, with slight modification so that it works.

First, start pyspark with the graphframes pkg loaded.

`pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6`

python code:

```py
from graphframes import *

# Create a Vertex DataFrame with unique ID column "id"
v = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
], ["id", "name", "age"])

# Create an Edge DataFrame with "src" and "dst" columns
e = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "b", "friend"),
  ("b", "c", "follow"),
  ("c", "b", "follow"),
], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])
# Create a GraphFrame
g = GraphFrame(v, e)

# Query: Get in-degree of each vertex.
g.inDegrees.show()

# Query: Count the number of "follow" connections in the graph.
g.edges.filter("relationship = 'follow'").count()

# Run PageRank algorithm, and show results.
results = g.pageRank(resetProbability=0.01, maxIter=20)
results.vertices.select("id", "pagerank").show()
```

Comment: Nice answer however I would recommend a later version of graphframes so something like 
--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.6.0-spark2.3-s_2.11

Answer (score 1):

No.

GraphX computation is only supported using the Scala and RDD APIs.

See https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/graph-analysis/graph-analysis-graphx-tutorial.html

GraphX is legacy and that makes sense.

Comment: Hard to follow your logic of other answer being correct irt original question.