# Apache GraphX Python Connector

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx

I have been working with graph databases like neo4j, blazegraph, aws neptune etc for last 3+ years.
I'm new to Apache GraphX. The only programming language I know is Python.
Is there a python connector against Apache GraphX? Does pyspark work in this context?
If not, which is the best programming language to build graphs and manipulate Apache GraphX?

Comment: Please describe what do you want to achieve - what kind of graph processing do you need

Comment: My client uses Apache Spark GraphX database. I'm thinking of a way to manipulate data in this database. Which programming language do I need to use to connect to this db?

Comment: GraphX is not a database like Neo4j, etc. - it's a library for processing of graph data: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html

Comment: seems graphx still does not have support for python. see [this on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/graphx/src/main).

Comment: @AlexOtt: ok , so do you means graphX is something like matplotlib in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run graphx with Python / pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302270/how-do-i-run-graphx-with-python-pyspark)